How to filter out the top Nth value of each row in a R dataframe?
There is a R dataframe, I want to filter out the top Nth value of each row with the rest values being set to 0.
For example, suppose the dataframe looks like the following table:
0.5 0.3 0.2 0.15 0.9
0.3 0.1 0.25 0.4 0.14
0.6 0.7 0.35 0.2 0.1
I want to keep the top 2 value of each row, and the rest should be set to 0. Then, the previous dataframe should be transformed into the following one:
0.5 0 0 0 0.9
0.3 0 0 0.4 0.14
0.6 0.7 0 0 0
Many thanks for your help :)

You have five answers to this question and it is still open. Could you mark one as accepted or clarify what is missing in order to mark the question as solved?

Based on @FelixJassler answer, here´s an alternative using apply
t(apply(df, 1, \(x) {
  z <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[2]
  ifelse(x < z, 0, x)
}))

     X1  X2 X3  X4  X5
[1,] 0.5 0.0  0 0.0 0.9
[2,] 0.3 0.0  0 0.4 0.0
[3,] 0.6 0.7  0 0.0 0.0


We can use rownth or rowRanks from the Rfast package, depending on whether we want to keep ties.
With ties:
library(Rfast)

df*(df >= rownth(as.matrix(df), rep(2, nrow(df)), 1, TRUE))
#>    X1  X2 X3  X4  X5  X6
#> 1 0.5 0.0  0 0.0 0.9 0.0
#> 2 0.3 0.0  0 0.4 0.0 0.3
#> 3 0.6 0.7  0 0.0 0.0 0.6

Without ties:
df*(rowRanks(as.matrix(df), "first", TRUE) <= 2)
#>    X1  X2 X3  X4  X5 X6
#> 1 0.5 0.0  0 0.0 0.9  0
#> 2 0.3 0.0  0 0.4 0.0  0
#> 3 0.6 0.7  0 0.0 0.0  0

A base solution without ties:
df <- as.matrix(df)
df[array(order(row(df), -df), rev(dim(df)))[-(1:2),]] <- 0
as.data.frame(df)
#>    X1  X2 X3  X4  X5 X6
#> 1 0.5 0.0  0 0.0 0.9  0
#> 2 0.3 0.0  0 0.4 0.0  0
#> 3 0.6 0.7  0 0.0 0.0  0

Data:
df <- data.frame(
  matrix(c(
    0.5, 0.3, 0.2,  0.15, 0.9, 0.4,
    0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.4,  0.14, 0.3,
    0.6, 0.7, 0.35, 0.2,  0.1, 0.6
  ), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
)

Benchmarking with a larger dataset. First the functions (modified to all return a data.frame):
Jilber <- function(df, k) {
  as.data.frame(
    t(apply(df, 1, \(x) {
      z <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[k]
      ifelse(x < z, 0, x)
    }))
  )
}

Jan <- function(df, k) {
  as.data.frame(df %>% pmap_dfr(~c(...) %>% replace(rank(desc(.)) > k, 0)))
}

jbloodTies <- function(df, k) {
  df*(df >= rownth(as.matrix(df), rep(k, nrow(df)), 1, TRUE))
}

jbloodNoTies <- function(df, k) df*(rowRanks(as.matrix(df), "first", TRUE) <= k)

jbloodBase <- function(df, k) {
  df <- as.matrix(df)
  df[array(order(row(df), -df), rev(dim(df)))[-(1:k),]] <- 0
  as.data.frame(df)
}

Felix <- function(df, k) {
  for(i in seq(nrow(df))) {
    largest <- sort(unlist(df[i,]), decreasing = TRUE)[k]
    indexes <- which(df[i,] < largest)
    df[i,indexes] <- 0
  }
  
  df
}

Friede <- function(df, kmax, fun) {
  df <- as.matrix(df)
  i = matrix(df[order(-row(df), df, decreasing = TRUE)], 
             nrow = nrow(df), byrow = TRUE)[, kmax]
  as.data.frame(df * sweep(df, 1L, i, fun))
}

Data and timing:
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e4), 100))
k <- 10

bench::mark(
  Jilber = Jilber(df, k),
  Jan = Jan(df, k),
  Felix = Felix(df, k),
  Friede = Friede(df, k, ">="),
  jbloodBase = jbloodBase(df, k),
  jbloodTies = jbloodTies(df, k),
  jbloodNoTies = jbloodNoTies(df, k)
)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#>   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 Jilber         8.91ms   9.72ms     89.2     1.72MB    13.6 
#> 2 Jan           23.44ms  27.16ms     35.6     3.27MB    13.8 
#> 3 Felix        309.87ms 314.32ms      3.18   14.69MB    19.1 
#> 4 Friede         1.47ms   1.75ms    490.    754.09KB     9.96
#> 5 jbloodBase     1.29ms   1.47ms    579.    445.15KB     9.98
#> 6 jbloodTies     9.72ms  10.48ms     85.1     1.18MB    13.9 
#> 7 jbloodNoTies   8.81ms   9.41ms     96.7   981.05KB    13.8

The most performant solutions are base R.

Ahhh, that's the {Rfast}-way to go. I checked the arguments of Rfast::rowMaxs() to no avail. (+1)

Base R
Possibly considerable fast. Happy to get some feedback on this.
foo = \(M, kmax, fun) {
   i = matrix(M[order(-row(M), M, decreasing = TRUE)], 
              nrow = nrow(M), byrow = TRUE)[, kmax]
   M * sweep(M, 1L, i, fun) }

foo(M, 2L, ">=")
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]  0.5  0.0    0  0.0  0.9
#> [2,]  0.3  0.0    0  0.4  0.0
#> [3,]  0.6  0.7    0  0.0  0.0

Wrapping in a small function (foo) and selecting these particular arguments is obviously not necessary.

Data:
M = matrix(c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2,  0.15, 0.9,
             0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.4,  0.14,
             0.6, 0.7, 0.35, 0.2,  0.1), 
           nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)


This is good +1. I came back to this question after I had the same idea with order(row( and noticed you had beat me to it.

A tidyverse solution:
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% pmap_dfr(~c(...) %>% replace(rank(desc(.)) > 2, 0))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
#     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   0.5   0       0   0     0.9
#2   0.3   0       0   0.4   0  
#3   0.6   0.7     0   0     0  

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(X1 = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.6), X2 = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.7), 
    X3 = c(0.2, 0.25, 0.35), X4 = c(0.15, 0.4, 0.2), X5 = c(0.9, 
    0.14, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


Here's one approach. Note that it might keep three or more values in a row if they are equivalent (since it only sets those values to 0 that are strictly smaller). If you only want 2 values, let me know :)
df <- data.frame(
  matrix(c(
    0.5, 0.3, 0.2,  0.15, 0.9,
    0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.4,  0.14,
    0.6, 0.7, 0.35, 0.2,  0.1
  ), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
)

for(i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  largest <- sort(unlist(df[i,]), decreasing = TRUE)[2]
  indexes <- which(df[i,] < largest)
  df[i,indexes] <- 0
}
#    X1  X2 X3  X4  X5
# 1 0.5 0.0  0 0.0 0.9
# 2 0.3 0.0  0 0.4 0.0
# 3 0.6 0.7  0 0.0 0.0

